# Undefined offset: 1 in gcm_action_send_message()

Tags: 6

I am using [Google Cloud Messaging](http://drupal.org/project/gcm) for one of my projects. I think I have configured everything correctly. I am getting the following error when I tried to send some message.

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in `gcm_action_send_message()`

I can't find any information in the module documentation.

Comment: May you show the code you are using?

Comment: @kiamlaluno, its all set up with configuration forms i am doing nothing via code.

Comment: this looks like something that would live better as a bug report in the issue queue than an open question here.

Comment: @DavidMeister, This is not a bug. Lack of documentation only. See my answer.

Comment: Not providing inline documentation for an API function is a bug in the documentation. According to http://drupal.org/node/1354#functions. File an issue please.

Comment: Questions about how to use a function exposed from a module or Drupal are allowed, whatever the documentation for that function exists, it is complete, it is not clear, incomplete, or missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer by looking the code used from the module.

```
function gcm_action_send_message($tokens, $keyValues, $delay_while_idle, $time_to_live, $collapse_key) {

    $gcm_message = array();
    foreach (explode(",", $keyValues) as $keyValue) {
      $temp = explode("=", $keyValue);
      $key = $temp[0];
      $value = $temp[1];
      if (isset($key) && isset($value)) {
        $gcm_message[$key] = $value;
      }
    }
    gcm_send_message(array_unique(explode(',', $tokens)), $gcm_message, $delay_while_idle, $time_to_live, $collapse_key);
}
```

So we need to use for key-values a value like 0=[site:name], 1=[site:mail].